# EF Core how to update entity based on object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am using .net core and ef core 2.1. I have the following piece of code where I try to get a list of entities from my context.  I then want to perform some operations based on that list and then update the entity then save it.  How would I go about doing this?  I'm open to suggestions on how to better structure this.

```
item = await _context.Items
    .Where(i => i.ItemId == xxx)
    .ToListAsync();

IList<Item> updatedItems;

if (items.Count > 0) {
    var docEntry = _context.Entry(documents);

    //cast the collection to Document type
    updatedItems = (IList<Items>)ds.PerformAction(items);  //perform some action in another service class and return a collection of updated items

    //now I want to merge/update my context to reflect the updated items
    foreach (Item itm in updatedItems){
        //update my context items
        item.ItemColor = itm.ItemColor //for matched items
    }
}

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't change `ds.PerformAction` to perform the changes on the original objects, join the results with the original items list to map the updated item to the original item entity:

```
var mappedItems = items.Join( 
    updatedItems, 
    // join criteria (pk selector)
    oi => oi.ItemId, 
    ii => ii.ItemId,
    ( oi, ii ) => new
        {
            OriginalItem = oi,
            UpdatedItem = ii,
        } );
```

Then perform whatever you need to do in a loop or similar construct:

```
foreach( var at in mappedItems )
{
    at.OriginalItem.ItemColor = at.UpdatedItem.ItemColor;
}
```